# Scrolling div within bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div with images inside it and need to scroll it left and right. I,ve managed to get the scrolling to work, but now I need it to stay in the displayable area.
I need to use jQuery

```
$('#next').click(function() {
$('#slides').animate({left: '-=80',}, 2000, function() {});
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
$('#slides').animate({left: '+=80',}, 2000, function() {});
});
```

The two "buttons" is used to scroll.
How do I get the slides' position.left to stay between 0 and -1120 ?

This will be the bottom of my slideshow. The large images will be at the top. 
How do I change the z-index of a div ?

Answer (score 0):

You change the z-index using css:

```
div.class {
  z-index: 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the width of your displayable area then by making use of the [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method.

If you have the maximum width you can use you can easily implement a check before your animation. So if the new width (current - 80) is bigger than 0, fine ... animate it. If not, don't.

Same for scrolling to the right. If it's bigger than your displayable area's **width**, then don't scroll.

**EDIT**
You changed your question slightly, so to get the current `left` value you can check it with:

```
$('#element').offset().left
```

This returns the current integer value of your `left` attribute. Thus again you can verify its current value and compare it with the one that it'd be like after you animated it. If it's too big or too small, don't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the css left value is in the interval:

```
if(parseInt($('#slides').css('left')) > -1120 && parseInt($('#slides').css('left')) < 0){
....//animate here
}
```